# Finding the coordinate with the lowest x in severel sections

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, point-clouds

I have a point cloud matrix with the coordinates of each point in the format x y z. I wanted to define a find the point with the lowest x in multiple sections of a certain region, defined by x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, z_min and z_max. Each section has a length of y_step. My main objective is to have a line of points so that I can plot a line of the furthest points.
I wrote this function, but it is not working (too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed)

```
> def edge(x_min,x_max,y_min,y_max,y_step,z_min, z_max, matrix):
>     x_edge = []
>     y_edge = []
>     z_edge = []
>     # filtered = matrix[matrix[:, 0] > x_min & matrix[:, 0] < x_max & matrix[:, 2] > z_min & matrix[:, 2] < z_max]
>     filtered = np.logical_and(matrix[:, 0] > x_min , matrix[:, 0] < x_max , matrix[:, 2] > z_min )#, matrix[:, 2] < z_max)
>     k = y_min + y_step
>     for k in np.arange(y_min, y_max, y_step):
>         # filtered2 = filtered[:, 1] > k-y_step & filtered[:, 1] < k
>         filtered2 = np.logical_and(filtered[:, 1] > k-y_step , filtered[:, 1] < k)
>         x_fil = filtered2[:, 0].min()
>         y_fil = filtered2[np.where(filtered2[:, 0] == x_fil), 1]
>         y_fil = filtered2[np.where(filtered2[:, 0] == x_fil), 2]
>         x_edge += x_fil
>         y_edge += y_fil
>         z_edge += z_fil
>         k = k + y_step
>     return x_edge, y_edge, z_edge
```

I think my main problem is in the lines that I try to filter my values under certain conditions
How could I eliminate all the rows that aren't inside that volume I want?

Comment: Can you show an example of `matrix`? And where does the error occur?

Comment: The error is this: filtered2 = np.logical_and(filtered[:, 1] > k-y_step , filtered[:, 1] < k)
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed and the matrix is something like this [[22.69617292 -6.51072256  1.20137172]
 [22.69174133 -6.62112373  1.2046748 ]
 [22.68835834 -6.70843843  1.19877931]
 ...
 [20.03100392  1.45164826  1.15078379]
 [20.01495217  1.48430549  1.14904621]
 [19.99616238  1.51121792  1.14229098]]

Comment: please prepare a sample example to work on and desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is no 'matrix' as you have in for example matlab.
It is just a 1-D list containing 1-D lists, so matrix[:,0] fails as you cannot index a 1-D list with two slices.

The easiest solution is to a line converting this to a numpy matrix.

```
import numpy as np

def edge(..., mat):
    matrix = np.matrix(mat)
    ...
    filtered = np.logical_and(matrix[:, 0] > x_min , matrix[:, 0] < x_max , matrix[:, 2] > z_min )
    ...
```

Although I recommend using another variable name than 'matrix' which is confusing with the numpy class.

Comment: My matrix comes form a pandas dataframe that I converted to a numpy array

Comment: What do you get for the type of your matrix? (when you do "print(type(matrix))" )
And if it is a numpy.matrix, what do you get for its shape? ( "print(matrix.shape)" )